# VBA - Get name of last added sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a code to get the name of the last added sheet to Excel.

I have tried this...

```
Sub test()
Dim lastAddedSheet As Worksheet
Dim oneSheet As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set lastAddedSheet = .Sheets(1)
    For Each oneSheet In .Sheets
        If Val(Mid(oneSheet.CodeName, 6)) > Val(Mid(lastAddedSheet.CodeName, 6)) Then
            Set lastAddedSheet = oneSheet
        End If
    Next oneSheet
End With
MsgBox lastAddedSheet.Name & " was last added."
End Sub
```

But it does not really work.

Comment: What doesn't really work about it? Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: I'm not certain there is a reliable way to do what you are trying to do. There is `codename` and `index` neither of which are going to be in an order based on creation date or time.

Comment: Furthermore the names of the sheets (and codename) are not guaranteed to increment.  I can open a new workbook, create two extra tabs (`sheet2` and `sheet3`), delete `sheet1`, add a new sheet `sheet4` save and reopen the workbook, add a new sheet `sheet1` and now `sheet1` was last added and appears 3rd in the index of 4 sheets. Both it's codename and index have no discernable ordering.

Comment: Reserve a portion of your workbook to store sheet `CodeName` upon the `Workbook_NewSheet` event.

Comment: It does not provide the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't **reliably** know what sheet was last added, because a sheet can be *inserted* before or after any existing sheet in a workbook, see [`Sheets.Add` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add).

Unless you're the one adding it. In which case, all you need to do is capture the `Worksheet` object returned by the `Add` method:

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add

Debug.Print newSheet.Name
```

Extracting the digits from the `CodeName` isn't going to be reliable either - especially if you assume that every sheet's code name begins with 5 letters. On a German machine, the `CodeName` of what we see as `Sheet1` would be `Tabelle1` - but then again the role of that digit is strictly to ensure uniqueness of the names of the `VBComponent` items in the VBA project, and none of it says it has anything to do with any sort of ordering.

Comment: Furthemore on the `codename` issue is that a workbook, once closed and reopened will start back at the lowest available codename number which is why we never see `Sheet512381` in a heavily used workbook.

Answer (score 2):

As per @MathieuGuindon his answer, I can't think of any "simple" way to safely return the name of the latest added sheet. However if you willing to sacrifice some designated space in your project to store `CodeNames` you could try to utilize the `Workbook_NewSheet` event.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim lr As Long
With Sheets("Blad1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(lr, 1) = ActiveSheet.CodeName
End With

End Sub
```

Obviously you need to optimize this to add names when adding sheets during runtime. In this simplified example I manually added the existing sheet "Blad1", and upon adding new sheets, the list grew.

When deleting you can utilize the `SheetBeforeDelete` event, like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim ws As Object
Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cl As Range
With Sheets("Blad1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        For Each cl In rng1
            If cl = ws.CodeName Then
                If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cl)
                Else
                    Set rng2 = cl
                End If
            End If
        Next cl
    Next ws
End With

If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    rng2.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Now to get the latest added sheet we can refer to the last cell in our designated range:

```
Sub LastAdded()

Dim lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print "Last added sheet is codenamed: " & .Cells(lr, 1)
End With

End Sub
```

My take on it is that it would be safest to use the `CodeName` since they are least likely to get changed and are unique. We can also safely keep using our `rng` variable since there will always be at least one worksheet in your project (and that might just be the designated one if you protect it). Working in this project will now keep track of latest added worksheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199646/discussion-between-jvdv-and-mathieu-guindon).

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets` could be a `Chart` or a `Worksheet`.
You could try use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` in your code.

```vb
sub test()
Dim lastAddedSheet As Worksheet
Dim oneSheet As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set lastAddedSheet = .WorkSheets(1)
    For Each oneSheet In .WorkSheets
        If Val(Mid(oneSheet.CodeName, 6)) > Val(Mid(lastAddedSheet.CodeName, 6)) Then
            Set lastAddedSheet = oneSheet
        End If
    Next oneSheet
End With
MsgBox lastAddedSheet.Name & " was last added."
End Sub
```

Comment: While iterating `Worksheets` when you mean to iterate *worksheets* is excellent advice, in this particular case it makes no difference, since a chart sheet has a `CodeName` too.

Comment: This doesn't work neither. However, thank you for your proposal.